# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, input, iterable-unpacking

In the Python tutorial book I'm using, I typed an example given for **simultaneous assignment**. I get the aforementioned ValueError when I run the program, and can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
#avg2.py
#A simple program to average two exam scores
#Illustrates use of multiple input

def main():
    print("This program computes the average of two exam scores.")

    score1, score2 = input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: ")
    average = (int(score1) + int(score2)) / 2.0

    print("The average of the scores is:", average)

main()
```

Here's the output.

```
>>> import avg2
This program computes the average of two exam scores.
Enter two scores separated by a comma: 69, 87
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import avg2
  File "C:\Python34\avg2.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\avg2.py", line 8, in main
    score1, score2 = input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python valueerror : too many values to unpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098478/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Comment: This is because of you are using python3 check my answer it may help you :)

Answer (score 11):

Judging by the prompt message, you forgot to call [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) at the end of the 8th line:

```
score1, score2 = input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: ").split(",")
#                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Doing so splits the input on the comma.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: ").split(",")
Enter two scores separated by a comma: 10,20
['10', '20']
>>> score1, score2 = input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: ").split(",")
Enter two scores separated by a comma: 10,20
>>> score1
'10'
>>> score2
'20'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

The above code will work fine on Python 2.x. Because `input` behaves as `raw_input` followed by a `eval` on Python 2.x as documented here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

However, above code throws the error you mentioned on Python 3.x. On Python 3.x you can use the `ast` module's [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method on the user input.

This is what I mean:

```
import ast

def main():
    print("This program computes the average of two exam scores.")

    score1, score2 = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: "))
    average = (int(score1) + int(score2)) / 2.0

    print("The average of the scores is:", average)

main()
```

Comment: Huh, never considered using `literal_eval` for that!

Answer (score 0):

This is because behavior of input changed in python3

In python2.7 input returns value and your program work fine in this version

But in python3 input returns string

try this and it will work fine!

```
score1, score2 = eval(input("Enter two scores separated by a comma: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

that means your function return more value!

ex:

in python2 the function `cv2.findContours()` return --> `contours, hierarchy`

but in python3 `findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy`

so when you use those function, `contours, hierachy = cv2.findContours(...)` is well by python2, but in python3 function return 3 value to 2 variable.

SO  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)