# Trying to extract Certificate information in Python

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, pyopenssl, m2crypto

I am very new to python and cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this task. I want to connect to a website and extract the certificate information such as issuer and expiration dates.

I have looked all over, tried all kinds of steps but because I am new I am getting lost in the socket, wrapper etc.

To make matters worse, I am in a proxy environment and it seems to really complicate things.

Does anyone know how I could connect and extract the information while behind the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7691293/) Answer:

> You can still the server certificate with the
>   ssl.get_server_certificate() function, but it returns it in PEM
>   format.
>
> ```
> import ssl
> print ssl.get_server_certificate(('server.test.com', 443))
> ```
>
> From here, I would use M2Crypto or OpenSSL to read the cert and get values:
>
> ```
> # M2Crypto
> cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.google.com', 443))
> x509 = M2Crypto.X509.load_cert_string(cert)
> x509.get_subject().as_text()
>  # 'C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=www.google.com'
> ```

Comment: Okay so if I attempt ` ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.google.com', 443)) `
I get a timeout error ` TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond `

I assume its because of my proxy but I do not know how to work around it.

Comment: I have got the ssl.get_server_certificate working but it tells me now that I have a value error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Its working for me so far. (python 2.7.15) 
Maybe this might help. [ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150952)

Comment: Your answer is 100 percent correct, I just ran it on my Mac at home with no issues. Its the dang proxy at work that is causing the problems.

Answer (score -2):

Python SSL lib don't deal with proxies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).